# How to debug Symfony command using Xdebug and phpStorm?

Tags: debugging, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

First of all let's start saying I am running the whole project in a Docker container and that means I don't have anything installed on the host.

Having that I am trying to debug a Symfony command which is kind of CLI script with the difference it's not being called as `php script.php` but as `bin/console command`.

What does the `console` file has inside it? See below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

set_time_limit(0);

/** @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';

$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(['--env', '-e'], getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(['--no-debug', '']) && $env !== 'prod';

if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run($input);
```

I have Xdebug installed and configured, I have phpStorm configured as well and that means using the browser (and the extension to enable/disable)  I can debug whatever I want.

Typically this is how the command is executed from the console (bash):

```
<path_to_symfony>/bin/console quote:notify -d 120 -e <some_email>
```

Options are optional here and that means I can call the same as:

```
<path_to_symfony>/bin/console quote:notify
```

It will work both ways. <strike>I am using the docs from [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm) to debug such command.</strike> Now this is how I am setting up the IDE to debug a Symfony command:

- Go to `Run/Debug Configuration`
- Click on Add button (little green + symbol)
- Choose PHP Script
- Name it as `SF Command`
- At File box I wrote `bin/console`
- At Arguments box I wrote `quote:notify` (which is my command)

But the IDE says first: `Error: file not specified or invalid` and then when I try to execute the command it says it's not a valid configuration. (also notice the little "X" which should means something is wrong)

[image]
[image]

What I am missing here? Can I get some help here? I am using the latest version of phpStorm.

Comment: 1) *"When I hit the play button on the debug bar"* Can you be more clear with this -- a screenshot should help. Because  .. on one hand -- to debug you need to click on "Debug" button on main/mini toolbar (on the top of the IDE); but on another hand -- there is"play" button indeed in Debug tool window ... bur for that debug session must be already started... 2) So far is sounds like missing bootstrap functionality .. so PHP does not know where to get parent/used class `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand`.

Comment: 3) Maybe you should launch it differently -- e.g. via `artisan` (or whatever Symfony uses for executing tasks from command line -- sorry, not a Symfony user here).

Comment: @LazyOne by *Play* I mean the button activated through `Shift + 10` key combination and yes it's on main/mini toolbar.

Comment: Well .. "Play" button there is just "Run/Execute this" and not "Debug this" .. so it's not debugging yet -- it cannot even just execute it. So far -- missing bootstrap logic (as you are calling that file directly possibly bypassing the needed logic).

Comment: @LazyOne Is there any guide besides the one I linked here to setup this maybe step by step?

Comment: All official guides are here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials . If I'm correct with missing bootstrapping .. then it's more Symfony-specific question. So .. please tell me -- how would you normally run that code in production?

Comment: @LazyOne pls take a look to the post again, I have removed some stuff and add a new ones, if you want start from there and forget all the previous attempts. (apologies I was busy and can't try this before)

Comment: As far as my understanding goes ... the path to the script should NOT be just `bin/console` -- it has to be full path to that file, e.g. `/path/to/current/project/bin/console`. or `/usr/bin/console` (or whatever the path to that script it)

Comment: Adding the docker commands at the front? I mean something like `docker exec -u www-data -it dockeramp_webserver_1 php symfony/bin/console quote:notify`?

Comment: AFAIK the docker part should be handled automatically -- taken from your current PHP Interpreter (it should know how to execute such stuff) - I'm not using Docker myself so cannot 100% guarantee all this. For example (test Laravel project): command in console would be `php artisan help`. This is how it look as a Run/Debug Configuration: http://postimg.org/image/vg4k0qdgf/ .. and this is the actual command that IDE executes: `E:\Projects\php\php\php.exe E:\Projects\web\_tests\laravel.dev\artisan help`

Comment: By adding the full path to the file `bin/console` makes the file valid but if I run it I got this error: `Error running Notify Command: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"repository dockeramp_php not found: does not exists or not pull access"}`

Comment: I'm not a Docker user so cannot advise here on possible reasons. Right now I may only suggest https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Docker+Support+in+PhpStorm and check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI for possible related tickets